# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a linear transformation with second order derivative of a polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Given is the following transformation of the 6th order polynomials (maximum 6th order).

$p(x) -> x^2 \frac{d^2p(x)}{dx^2} + c$

Ok first question. When is this transformation linear. I found only when the c value = 0 because:

$constant*T(p(x))$ is not equal to $T(constant * p(x))$

It is only equal when c =0 (if i am right offcourse)

Next question is to find the exact description of the kernel and the range with the value for c found in the first question.

Kernel: all first order polynomials. $a_0 + a_1 x$

Range
$2a_2x^2+6a_3x^3+12a_4x^4+20a_5x^5+30a_6x^6$

And last but not leat. Find all the eigenvectors and eigenvalues. Here I found only 5 of them (but the dimension is 7?)

$vector: x^2$ and $\lambda = 2$

$vector: x^3$ and $\lambda = 6$

$vector: x^4$ and $\lambda = 12$

$vector: x^5$ and $\lambda = 20$

$vector: x^6$ and $\lambda = 30$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in stating that we must have $c = 0$. With respect to the standard basis $\{1,x,\dots,x^6\}$, the transformation is given by the diagonal matrix
$$
\pmatrix{
0\\
&0\\
&&2\\
&&&6\\
&&&&12\\
&&&&&20\\
&&&&&&30
}
$$
and so it is clear what the eigenvalues of the transformation are.
The two eigenvalues you are missing are $\lambda = 0$ (with multiplicity $2$).  The corresponding eigenvectors are simply those that form the kernel of the transformation.

Comment: Ok. So the 0 eigenvalues correspond to eigenvectors: a constant and x?

I thought 0 was not valid because when you do the transformation you get: $x= 0*x^2$ because of the $x^2$ multiplication.

Comment: We have $x \mapsto 0 \cdot x^2 = 0$.  Remember that the zero vector in a vector-space is always unique.

Comment: But i thought that the zero vector couldnt be an eigenvector ?

Comment: That's correct.  $x$ is an eigenvector though, because $x \mapsto 0 \cdot x$.  That is, $x \mapsto \lambda x$, with $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: But isn't x projected on $0 x^2$

You differentiate 2 times so you get zero, but you multiplicate with $x^2$ Ok the result is both 0. But....

Comment: $0x^2 = 0x = 0$.  This is by the definition of the equality of two polynomials.  If you want to convince yourself that this is the case, ask yourself the following: given polynomials $p(x),q(x)$, what does it mean to say $p = q$?  Does it make sense to say $0x \neq 0x^2$?

Comment: Ok, but it is math :D and sometimes they have that weird kind of definitions. But I got it. Thank you :)